# Multi user site and image captions

Tags: captions, multi-author

On multi user sites when authors select images from the media library they can choose images that other authors have uploaded.

The problem is that they can edit the caption and it changes it for both the post they're making and any previous posts that have the same image and caption, this doesn't make any sense.

Is there a way to stop authors from user images uploaded by other authors or fixing the image caption problem?

Comment: Have you tried [The plugins mentioned _HERE_](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Resources)?

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this in WP 4.5 with the default author role and this issue doesn't seem to exist anymore. My findings:

1 As an author you cannot edit media properties directly.

2 As an author you can edit media properties when you are inserting an image in a post. This will cause the image to be included with an `alt` tag containing the edit, but the edit will not be stored in the database.